# How to convert 16-bit audio created with Android's AudioRecord to 12-bit audio through bit shifting?

Tags: java, android, audio, bit-manipulation, audiorecord

I am attempting to convert 16 bit audio into 12 bit audio. However, I am quite inexperienced with such conversions and believe my approach is possibly incorrect or flawed.

The use case, as context for the code snippets below, is an Android app which the user can speak into and that audio is transmitted to an IoT device for immediate playback. The IoT device expects audio in mono 12 bit, 8k sample rate, little endian, unsigned, with the data stored in the first twelve bits (0-11) and final four bits (12-15) are zeroes. Audio data needs to be received in packets of 1000 bytes.

The audio is being created in the Android app through the use of AudioRecord. The instantiation of which is as follows:

```
int bufferSize = 1000;
        this.audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                bufferSize
        );
```

In a while loop, the AudioRecord is being read from by 1000 byte packets and modified to the specifications in the use case. Not sure this part is relevant, but for completeness:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            byte[] modifiedBytes = convert16BitTo12Bit(buffer);
```

Then the modifiedBytes are sent off to the device.

Here are the methods which modify the bytes. Basically, to conform to the specifications, I am shifting the bits in each 16 bit set (tossing the least significant 4) and adding zeroes to the final four spots. I do this through BitSet.

```
    /**
     * Takes a byte array presented as 16 bit audio and converts it to 12 bit audio through bit
     * manipulation. Packets must be of 1000 bytes or no manipulation will occur and the input
     * will be immediately returned.
     */
    private byte[] convert16BitTo12Bit(byte[] input) {
        if (input.length == 1000) {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i += 2) {
                Log.d(TAG, "convert16BitTo12Bit: pass #" + (i / 2));
                byte[] chunk = new byte[2];
                System.arraycopy(input, i, chunk, 0, 2);
                if (!isEmptyByteArray(chunk)) {
                    byte[] modifiedBytes = convertChunk(chunk);
                    System.arraycopy(
                            modifiedBytes,
                            0,
                            input,
                            i,
                            modifiedBytes.length
                    );
                }
            }
            return input;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "convert16BitTo12Bit: Failed - input is not 1000 in length; it is " + input.length);
        return input;
    }

    /**
     * Converts 2 bytes 16 bit audio into 12 bit audio. If the input is not 2 bytes, the input
     * will be returned without manipulation.
     */
    private byte[] convertChunk(byte[] chunk) {
        if (chunk.length == 2) {
            BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(chunk);
            Log.d(TAG, "convertChunk: bitSet starts as " + bitSet.toString());
            modifyBitSet(bitSet);
            Log.d(TAG, "convertChunk: bitSet ends as " + bitSet.toString());
            return bitSet.toByteArray();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "convertChunk: Failed = chunk is not 2 in length; it is " + chunk.length);
        return chunk;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the first four bits and shifts the rest to leave the final four bits as 0.
     */
    private void modifyBitSet(BitSet bitSet) {
        for (int i = 4; i < bitSet.length(); i++) {
            bitSet.set(i - 4, bitSet.get(i));
        }
        if (bitSet.length() > 8) {
            bitSet.clear(12, 16);
        } else {
            bitSet.clear(4, 8);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the byte array input contains all zero bits.
     */
    private boolean isEmptyByteArray(byte[] input) {
        BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(input);
        return bitSet.isEmpty();
    }
```

Unfortunately, this approach produces subpar results. The audio is quite noisy and it is difficult to make out what someone is saying (but you can hear that words are being spoken).

I also have been playing around with just saving the bytes to a file and playing it back on Android through AudioTrack. I noticed that if I just remove the first four bits and do not shift anything, the audio actually sounds good, as such:

```
        private void modifyBitSet(BitSet bitSet) {
        bitSet.clear(0, 4);
    }
```

However, when played through the device, it sounds even worse, and I don't even think I can make out any words.

Clearly, my approach is not working here. **Central question is how would one convert a 16 bit chunk into 12 bit audio and maintain audio quality given the requirement that the final four bits must be zero? Additionally, given my larger approach of using AudioRecord to obtain the audio, would such a solution for the prior question fit this use case?**

Please let me know if there is anything more I can provide to clarify these questions and my intent.

Comment: Are you sure that you can just clear the first 4 bits and not concat 12 bits close to each other `1111111111110000 1111111111110000` --> `1111111111111111 1111111100000000`?

Comment: @Darkman Bit modification is all rather new to me; I've never had to do it before... so I am really not sure what would be ideal. I am operating on the idea that the least significant four bits should be removed to retain the best audio quality. And that actually works as long as I do not shift anything. So something has gone wrong in the shifting.

Could you clarify your approach here? How are you concatenating the bits in your example? Given that the audio is 16 bits but must be changed to 12 with four zeros at the end, four bits somewhere do have to be tossed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered a solution that produces clear audio. First, it is important to recount the requirements for the use case, which is 12 bit unsigned mono audio which will be read in little endian by the device in packets of 1000 bytes.

The initialization and configuration of the AudioRecord as described in the question is fine.

Once the 1000 bytes of audio is read from AudioRecord, it can be put into a ByteBuffer and defined as little endian for modification, and then put into a ShortBuffer to do manipulation on the 16 bit level:

```
        // Audio specifications of device is in little endian.
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(input).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        // Turn into a ShortBuffer so bitwise manipulation can occur on the 16 bit level.
        ShortBuffer shortBuffer = byteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
```

Next, in a loop, take each short and modify it to 12 bit unsigned:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < shortBuffer.capacity(); i++) {
            short currentShort = shortBuffer.get(i);
            shortBuffer.put(i, convertShortTo12Bit(currentShort));
        }
```

This can be accomplished by shifting the 16 bits four spaces to the right to turn it into 12 bit signed. Then, to convert to unsigned, add 2048. For our purposes as a safety step, we also mask the least significant four bits as required by device, but given the shifting and adding, it shouldn't be the case that any bits actually remain there:

```
    private static short convertShortTo12Bit(short input) {
        int inputAsInt = input;
        inputAsInt >>>= 4;
        inputAsInt += 2048;
        input = (short) (inputAsInt & 0B0000111111111111);
        return input;
    }
```

If one wishes to return 12 bits to 16 bits, do the reverse for each short (subtract 2048 and shift four spaces to the left).

Answer (score 0):

> Given that the audio is 16 bits but must be changed to 12 with four zeros at the end, four bits somewhere do have to be tossed.

Yes,  of course and there is no other way, is there?

This is something quick that I can comeout with right now. Certainly not fully tested though. Only tested with input of 2 and 4 bytes. I'll leave it to you to test it.

```
    //Reminder :: Convert as many as possible.
    //Reminder :: To calculate the required size for store: 
    //if((bytes.length & 1) == 0) Math.round((bytes.length * 6) / 8F) : Math.round(((bytes.length - 1) * 6) / 8F).
    //Return :: Amount of converted bytes.
    public static final int convert16BitTo12Bit(final byte[] bytes, final byte[] store) 
    {
        final int size = bytes.length;
        int storeIndex = 0;
        //Copy the first 2 bytes into store.
        store[storeIndex++] = bytes[0]; store[storeIndex] = bytes[1];
        if(size < 4) {
               store[storeIndex] = (byte)(store[storeIndex] & 0xF0);
               return 2;
                }
        final int result;
        final byte tmp;
        //  11111111 11110000 00000000 00000000
        //+              11111111 11110000      (<< 12)
        //= 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 (1)
        //-----------------------------------------
        //  11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 (1)
        //+          11111111 11110000          (<< 16)
        //= 11111111 11111111 11110000 00000000 (2)
        //-----------------------------------------
        //  11110000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (2)
        //+     1111 11111111 0000              (<< 20)
        //= 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 (3)
        //-----------------------------------------
        //  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (3)
        //+ 11111111 11110000                   (<< 24)
        //= 11111111 11110000 00000000 00000000
        for(int i=2, shiftBits = 12; i < size; i += 2) {
            if(shiftBits == 24) {
                //Copy 2 bytes from bytes[] into store[] and move on.
                store[storeIndex] = bytes[i];
                //Never store byte 0 (Garbage).
                tmp = (byte)(bytes[i + 1] & 0xF0); //Bit order: 11110000.
                if(tmp != 0) store[++storeIndex] = tmp;
                shiftBits = 12; //Reset
            } else if(shiftBits == 20) {
                result = ((store[storeIndex - 1] << 24) | ((store[storeIndex] & 0xFF) << 16))
                    | (((bytes[i] & 0xFF) << 20) | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF) << 12));
                store[storeIndex] = (byte)((result >> 24) & 0xFF);
                tmp = (byte)((result >> 16) & 0xFF);
                //Never store byte 0 (Garbage).
                if(tmp != 0) store[++storeIndex] = tmp;
                shiftBits = 24;
            } else if(shiftBits == 16) {
                result = ((store[storeIndex - 1] << 24) | ((store[storeIndex] & 0xFF) << 16))
                    | (((bytes[i] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF) << 8));
                store[storeIndex] = (byte)((result >> 16) & 0xFF);
                tmp = (byte)((result >> 8) & 0xF0);
                //Never store byte 0 (Garbage).
                if(tmp != 0) store[++storeIndex] = tmp;
                shiftBits = 20;
            } else {
                result = ((store[storeIndex - 1] << 24) | ((store[storeIndex] & 0xFF) << 16))
                    | (((bytes[i] & 0xFF) << 12) | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF) << 4));
                store[storeIndex] = (byte)((result >> 16) & 0xFF);
                tmp = (byte)((result >> 8) & 0xFF);
                //Never store byte 0 (Garbage).
                if(tmp != 0) store[++storeIndex] = tmp;
                shiftBits = 16;
            }
        }
        return ++storeIndex;
    }
```

**Explanations**

```
result = ((store[storeIndex - 1] << 24) | ((store[storeIndex] & 0xFF) << 16))
                    | (((bytes[i] & 0xFF) << 20) | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF) << 12));
```

- What this does is basically merge two integers into one.

```
((store[storeIndex - 1] << 24) | ((store[storeIndex] & 0xFF) << 16))
```

- The first one is make an integer with same constant bit position.

```
(((bytes[i] & 0xFF) << 20) | ((bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF) << 12));
```

- The latter is for 2 current bytes with different bit positions.

```
(...) | (...)
```

- Pipe or vertical bar at the middle is to merge these two integers we've just created into one.

**Usage**

To use this method is pretty straight forward.

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
    byte[] store;
    if((buffer.length & 1) == 0) { //Even.
        store = new byte[Math.round((bytes.length * 6) / 8F)];
    } else { //Odd.
        store = new byte[Math.round(((bytes.length - 1) * 6) / 8F)]; 
    }
    audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    int convertedByteSize = convert16BitTo12Bit(buffer, store);
    System.out.println("size: " + convertedByteSize);
```

Comment: I tested this out and it unfortunately did not work; the audio was incomprehensible. A question about the store's size to clarify intent: it appears that in the "usage" code block, the store will always be the same size because the buffer always starts at 1000 in the line before. Is this purposeful or in error to invoke the code at that location? The store always ends up being 750 bytes in length, and it appears that perhaps the last chunk of the array (100+ bytes) is always completely zeroes.

Comment: Well, actually it doesn't start at 1000. 1000 is the size of the array named `buffer` that you wanna pass to `audioRecord`. It will always convert bytes from `buffer` at index 0. 750 bytes - Yes, that is how much spaces it requires for 1000 16-bit bytes to 12-bit bytes. For example: Full 4-byte 16-bit requires 4 bytes `[11111111 11111111] [11111111 111111111]` instead of 3 bytes for 12-bit `[11111111 1111][1111 11111111]`. This is similar to images with 24-bit vs 8-bit depth which has bigger size.

Comment: I suggest you to try to change `bitSet.clear(12, 16);` to `bitSet.clear(8, 12);` and `bitSet.clear(4, 8);` to `bitSet.clear(0, 4);` and see what will happen.

Comment: If I now understand correctly, what is being missed from the question by this answer is the zero padding. This approach is merging two sets of 16 bits across four bytes into two sets of 12 bits across three bytes. So at least the conversion is occurring. But, the data needs to be represented as 12 bits in 16 bits (with final four as 0, so 12 bits across 4 bytes `[11111111 11110000] [11111111 11110000]`. That's why I was confused about the 750 size. How might one go about this? Should the results of the 750 bytes be zero padded and shifted through some additional method?

Comment: Don't know how to edit comments, but I meant to say "But, the data [in your example of three bytes] needs to be represented as [two sets of] 12 bits in 16 bits (with final four as 0, so 12 bits across 4 bytes..."

Comment: Whahhhaha... I think both of us misunderstood each other. Oh well. I think what you want is just clear 4 least significant bits (LBS). My previous comment just leads you to that redirection. In LBS case, just `&` with `0xF0` (1111 0000) is more efficient. Or if you wanna clear 4 leading bits, `&` with `0x0F` (0000 11111). For example: `for(int i=1; i<buffer.length; i+=2) buffer[i]=(byte)(buffer[i] & 0xF0)` to clear 4 trailing bits for each two bytes. Note: `i`  should starts with 1 for LBS and 0 for MSB.